# Navigation Bar Inherit methods list

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I had inherited a class with UINavigationBar. Now I want to see a list methods that are available to override in this class like. I think these methods exist in navigation bar due to inheritance but how I can see list of these methods.

```
 - (void)applyDefaultStyle
 - (void)didMoveToSuperview
```

How I can see the list of these methods that is not current written in UINavigationBar documented methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no single list of methods for any class. Instead, you need to look at the methods in the class, the methods in all the classes that class inherits from, and the protocols implemented by that class or any of its superclasses.

Answer (score 2):

The `UINavigationBar` class inherits directly from `UIView`, and indirectly from `UIResponder` and `NSObject`. So `UINavigationBar` will have its own methods and also the `UIView`, `UIResponder` and `NSObject` methods.